# What tools (ideally affordable ones) would folks recommend for creating a website wireframe?

Tags: website-design, wireframe, tools, sketching

What tools (ideally affordable ones) would folks recommend for creating a
website wireframe? What tools have you used, and did you find them better than pen and paper?

Comment: Where does this question belong if not on this site? I came here *specifically* looking for something exactly like this.

Answer (score 27):

We use [Balsamiq Mockups](http://balsamiq.com/products/mockups) religiously these days. It's such a rapid tool for quickly creating rough outlines and even simple interactive walkthroughs. It's very cheap and has a free trial but also gives out free licnences to community projects. Give the desktop version a try, we've been using it for the past few months now and made it a part of our specification and prototyping process.

Comment: Agreed, this works really well for rough mockups and has some great features. Shame it's made in Adobe AIR though; it can be a little inconsistent and buggy.

Comment: We've tried many wireframing tools and settled with Balsamiq as well. It's feature set and philosophy are very much in tune with the view that wireframing should be ... well, wireframing, quick, low-fi and simple. Also, major props to the creators for a smart use of Comic Sans :).

Answer (score 27):

Paper is relatively inexpensive these days.

Also, I prefer pencils because of their rubber undo button.

Comment: I wish I could give two upvotes for added "undo button" sarcasm.

Comment: I prefer pens because they have *no* undo button. You'll think twice before making a change.

Comment: -1 for all the negatives that a physical model bring. Inconsistent legibility, no long distance collaboration, poor versioning, difficult to iterate, slow to make minor changes on a built up wireframe, needs post processing with a scanner or camera, digital version consumes more data, waste of paper.

Answer (score 12):

I find myself using simple pen and paper to quickly sketch some wireframes and then move on to the html/css prototype. Mostly since I'm a good integrator, prototyping early is easier than using complex software to wireframe.

Else, I'd recommend Omnigraffle, not too expensive and with the right stencils, it does great work. [Linky](http://www.omnigroup.com/applications/OmniGraffle/). It's useful for both wireframing and sitemapping.

Comment: I need to start using Omnigraffle, next, because we're leaving Visio behind now that we all have Macs at work. Any tips?

Comment: JeromeR, I guess I'd point you to some excellent stencils to get started with Omnigraffle and wireframing: http://konigi.com/tools/omnigraffle-wireframe-stencils -- I also find these work best: http://konigi.com/store/product/omnigraffle-sketch-stencils in order to make your wireframes more "sketchy" and less "oh, just integrate it now and we'll have a final product", which could be the response of some clients.

The tool itself if fairly easy to use, but it's not exactly familiar at first, needs a little practice.

Answer (score 12):

I have to agree with some of the other posters here.  Paper and pencil (or pen or marker) is the best, cheapest way to start your prototyping.  There's no reason to use something like Photoshop, because you aren't doing a full-blown design.  The various software packages specifically for mockups and prototypes are all nice, but can become very expensive, and also don't really add much beyond what paper can do for you.  I would say that they are rarely even more efficient time-wise.

If you do want to go with a prototyping application, I think that the best option out there is Axure.  They aren't overly expensive, and have a great amount of features.  And you can try the software for free for 30 days (and I think that's fully functional during that time as well).

I would recommend against using HTML/CSS for your prototypes unless you know that the people you are creating the prototypes for understand completely the difference between an HTML prototype and an actual, functioning site.  Typically, one of two things happens:

1. They focus on the aesthetics instead of the functionality, because "it's already a website, so it should look good".
2. They don't understand why you can't just finish it a couple of days after you show them the prototype, becuase "the site is already working, we just need to make it look prettier".  It takes a *lot* of work to get non-technical people to understand the difference between an HTML prototype and an actual functioning site.

As for PowerPoint — in my opinion, that is one of the most overused and misused applications around.  I can't count the number of times that I've received a PowerPoint presentation as an attachment as the sole means of announcing something by an HR person.  Using it for prototyping is along the same lines.  It was not designed for that and it does not really have the tools to make it effective for prototyping.

Answer (score 9):

I mostly use a notebook to sketch out super rough ideas, then I use Omnigraffle with the Konigi.com stencils to do the actual mock ups.

If I'm doing WoZ testing, then I do it all in paper with printed out browser elements.

Comment: Another vote for pen and paper from me too :-)

Answer (score 8):

At UPA conference a half year ago, I was in a session in which people discussed tools: HTML vs Axure vs Balsamiq vs FlairBuilder for prototyping.

Axure and Balsamiq got some votes. FlairBuilder gets my vote.

I was live-twittering, and someone outside the session suggested we download and try the FlairBuilder demo. We did so on the fly, and were immediately able to use it without any prior experience. FlairBuilder is at the same price point as Balsamiq, and each had some features that the other didn't. For example, FlairBuilder has live multimedia, including from YouTube, which was important to some participants and not others.

During the discussion, one participant said “Visio is a nightmare,” and while I think that's a strong statement, I am required to use it at work and I do find myself "fighting" Visio (i.e. wasting my time).

Microsoft was at that conference demonstrating a new design/sketching tool that produces low-fidelity prototypes, but that had a higher price point. I forget the product name [edit: It's [SketchFlow](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/Sketchflow%5FOverview.aspx)], but the demo was impressive, "as you would expect any hands-off demo to be," he added cynically. This product was not discussed in the discussion session I described, above [edit: because it wasn't yet released].

I recommend trying [FlairBuilder](http://www.flairbuilder.com/), because it's easy to use and learn, especialy if you start by amending the sample project. You'll have to overlook the frequent "Buy me now!" message in the free trial version.

*I am not affiliated with nor paid by any product mentioned, above.*

Comment: When looking into low-cost wireframing tools I found FlairBuilder to be preferable to Balsamiq. I'd prefer Axure over either, but it costs around 6 times more, so I've not managed to talk the bosses into that yet!

Answer (score 8):

I've given talks with:

FlairBuilder
Balsmiq
Axure
SketchFlow
PowerPoint
Fireworks

Personally, I start on a white-board.  I think FlairBuilder & Balsmiq are both extremely easy to use - perhaps the easiest.

I think Axure is really powerful, but not as friendly.

I think PowerPoint works when you are trying to do something really fast on a random PC.

My personal favorite is SketchFlow because of the way they link pages together and its ability to create behaviors and morph into a fully fledged working proto-type (really high fidelty) that can serve as the beginning code of a Silverlight Application or awesome doc for a development team on another technology.

I also like the animation capture & design, as well as, behavior/control building compared to the other programs which only really use pre-designed or low-fidelty custom controls.

Answer (score 7):

Fireworks is an amazing tool which is often overlooked -- it's really matured especially for doing lots of documentation and states.

The biggest advantage Fireworks has over other solutions is that it can be used for Webapps not just webpage. There is a huge difference in the level of complexity that needs to be wireframed between the two; this is often not accounted for in MOST wireframing tools.

Answer (score 7):

I have used: Visio, Illustrator, Axure RP Pro, OmniGraffle, Balsamiq Mockups seriously, and have tried all the web-based apps. I have also done HTML prototyping and paper prototyping.

What I find works most efficiently still is sketchiing on paper, refining in either OmniGraffle or going directly to mockups in HTML. What I choose to deliver depends on who the design document is for, and what its purpose is. Mostly I choose OmniGraffle for speed, or deliver sketches and HTML. Disclaimer is that I am in an in-house UI designer.

Answer (score 7):

I tend to grab a Stabilo Poit 88 pen, whichever colour takes my fancy and scamp out ideas on a wireframe sketch pad of my own design (6 x up on A4 landscape).

I've also found if you cut a block of square Post-It notes, cut down to 2/3 width work well - it forces you not to get stuck into details, but concentrate on the overall page.

Then I go over certain areas with a different colour to create point of interest/action. Then I sketch more detail at a larger scale (2 x up on A4 landscape).

Once happy with the direction and concepts I move over to OmniGraffle, using a personal template and various stencils (try Konigi.com & graffletopia.com). If anything trips me up at this stage, it's back to the pen & paper.

Finally I save my Omni doc as a PDF containing click-able links.

Answer (score 6):

You could try the new [Blend SketchFlow](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/Sketchflow%5FOverview.aspx) tool from Microsoft. It's incredibly powerful, but can be a little hard to approach (try sideways and with a slice of lemon).

It can generate prototypes viewable on the web (using Silverlight) or a Windows desktop app using WPF with a complete navigation system, and I believe it can track users. It can also record user comments as they're running through it...

Comment: There's a good vide on the mix website - http://videos.visitmix.com/MIX09/c01f

Answer (score 5):

Personally i use Pen and Paper (i particularly like [konigi's wireframe graph paper](http://konigi.com/tools/graph-paper)) then rendered into Visio, with the Lombardi wireframe templates and Nick Fink's wirefame stencils (these are both free). So apart from the cost of MS Visio it suites me well.

In the past I've also used:

- **PowerPoint** to create "clickable"
  wireframes but never in anger.
- **Axure** to spawn quick prototypes but the
  version i used didn't do a go job of
  collapsing the dynamic panel when the states were diffent heights (may be better now)

Matt

Answer (score 5):

I'm all about using pencil and paper (actually a sharpie and paper). I get the general look of things after I decide what elements are most important and then just straight into HTML.

I've used Photoshop and Balsamiq and Omnigraffle before, but I always felt like I was wasting my time because no matter how pretty they looked, I'd have to start all over when I got to the markup.

I felt much better about crumpling up a piece of paper I worked on for 10 minutes than I felt about deleting an Omnigraffle file I worked on for a few hours.

Answer (score 5):

Been a user of **PowerPoint** for some time but got tired of it's limited features and the fact theat they aren't interactive..

Although it isn't the cheapest option, I must say that **[pidoco](http://pidoco.com)** seems to be one of the best wireframe tool solutions for my needs since they're browser-based and let me export to various formats and get my work reviewd quickly. Yea, the review features are pretty cool indeed..

Surely there are several good mockup tools about but they mostly lack portability..so yea, pidoco is the solution for me so far!

Comment: I followed your advice and searched for Pidoco. I visited their site and only by the look of it I got frustrated - no way I will trust them with my time. In fact, I am asking a new question on how they can improve their site!

Answer (score 5):

We use Adobe InDesign. It may look strange a bit but there are features that I like:

- it has an 'Adobe-style' interface. If you've worked with Photoshop or some other Adobe products, it would be easy to learn how to use InDesign
- it can export your wireframes as clickable PDFs
- it has powerful abilities to work with typography, tables, styles, grids and so on
- it's easy to create not only a simple wireframe but a complex visual design too if needed

Answer (score 4):

Pencil for FireFox is a free flugin and can run as a standalone tool also.

The next up is something like Open Office Draw (also free).

Pen and paper are good also.

You can also try something like FlairBuilder which is an AIR app.

Comment: The desktop version of Pencil is now awesome. Plus you now have some excellent [stencil libraries](http://nathanielw.github.io/pencil-stencils/) for Bootstrap, Android and Material Design that have been created

Answer (score 4):

Using Photoshop, I edit the .psd in the 960 Grid (http://960.gs/) to create wireframes.

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty happy with starting out with pencil sketches then moving to OmniGraffle.

We've used FlairBuilder as well.  It's decent for wireframes and very simple prototypes, but we ran into a number of limitations.  As we continued to update the prototype, we found it became painfully slow. We're now considering Axure for prototyping.

Answer (score 4):

I use Post-its for structure and overall layout, then move on to Balsamiq Mockups or OmniGraffle, and for High-fidelity prototypes, nothing beats Apple Keynote. :)

Answer (score 3):

I can't say enough good things about http://hello.hotgloo.com/
I've been using it for collaborative wire framing and it's awesome.

Oh and it's free while they are in beta.

Answer (score 3):

I love iPlotz. Some of the features that sold me:

- Affordable!
- Task management
- Clickable prototypes
- Export to image or PDF
- Sharing and commenting capabilities
- Simple user interface with numerous widgets available
- Skins for sketch, Windows, and Mac

Before iPlotz, I used Photoshop.

- Candace

Answer (score 3):

I use Balsamiq Mockups for Wireframes. If the design is interactive i use Powerpoint. For high fidelity mockups, powerpoint is king.

Answer (score 3):

About the high fidelity prototyping tools, there are those that allow you to simulate to almost final design and effects, such as iRise and [Justinmind Prototyper](http://www.justinmind.com). Those don't just simply allow you to sketch the wireframe, but to embed videos, create rich interactions (such as form filling and data use), and are better to create specifications and user testing.

They're a step further from simple drawing tools like Visio, OG or Balsamiq.

Answer (score 3):

We tried several wireframing tools, but settled for [pidoco.com](https://pidoco.com/en) since it has some useful usability testing stuff integrated and is all online.

Answer (score 3):

Fireworks, hands down is one the best tools out there; not only for wireframing but for transitioning from wireframe to mockup and exporting interactive HTML prototypes.

It offers a nice component library. The tools are easy to figure out. It supports pages, and states.

It may not be the cheapest choice but in all honesty it is one of the best tools out there.

Comment: The major problem with FW is that its GUI performance is a major drag (and type rendering is at least questionable). Sadly – I used it extensively until ca. 6 years ago when it started to heavily suffer from bloatware symptoms and half-assed QA.

Answer (score 2):

I've used (and have been very impressed with) Balsamiq Mockups, but as Nathanel says, it has some limitations.

Not sure whether you've seen it or not but [Sitepoint posted this](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/tools-prototyping-wireframing) a few months back, but it's probably still relevant. Might be a few things worth more detailed investigation.

Answer (score 2):

Like most people here it seems, I use Balsamiq to do rough mockups on the fly, but the limitations of the interface (and the occasional tendency to crash) mandate that for more solid wireframing work I use Omnigraffle, usually with the Konigi stencils but increasingly also with my own. I find that once you've invested the time it takes to get used to creating templates and stencils, as well as mastering shared layers and variables, Omnigraffle is the perfect combination of powerful, feature-rich application and quick/easy production. The only drawback of course is that you can't easily share it with Visio people. They say you can using the XML-based file exports that both packages support, but it never really works flawlessly and you find yourself manually sorting out all the glitches.

Comment: I've found exactly the same problem with Omnigraffle and Visio, as most of my clients use or have access to visio this essentially rules out omnigraffle.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you take a look at EightShapes Unify (http://unify.eightshapes.com/) ... I've just started looking at it and haven't gotten a new project to try it out with, but it really looks like a killer framework for Wireframes *and* other design deliverables.

PS It's totally free but you need Adobe InDesign to use it.

Answer (score 2):

I switched from Balsamiq+Napkee to iPlotz - absolutely love it, since you can create a working rough prototype while making your mockups with no extra work. I did a writeup on it here:
http://www.snipe.net/2010/02/wireframes/

Answer (score 2):

Like all things, this depends on what it is you are hoping to achieve.

I used Powerpoint for a long time and that was fine.

The most comprehensive wireframing tool I've come across is Axure (http://www.axure.com/) which is great for creating high fidelity navigable wireframes. Plus its recently been launched for mac.

I find Balsmiq (http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups) a little fiddly, although I like the 'sketch' approach as if your looking for feedback, I've found the more polished something looks - the less likely you are to get feedback due to the fear that it's too far down the line.

http://gomockingbird.com/ is a great free tool, but quite basic.

If you have a mac, Omnigraffle is great and you can download a range of free stencils from http://graffletopia.com/

But never under estimate the power of pen and paper - this is by far the best for churning ideas out quickly

Answer (score 2):

This blog post about using Google docs, Google drawings sounds intriguing:

http://mortenjust.com/2010/04/19/a-wireframe-kit-for-google-drawings/

Answer (score 2):

The most suitable tools for wireframing and prototyping depend largely e.g. on your team structure (inter-operability, shareability, …), the project status (=> necessary visual and functional fidelity) and the type of stakeholders you need to communicate your design to. If you are working at least partly remote with a distributed team, requirements are quite different compared to having everybody on site. Further influencers comprise e.g. distributed editing and versioning. (IMHO, Zaki Warfel's book on prototyping provides a useful starting point when yo need to evaluate alternatives.)

My own workflow revolves largely around paper (freehand sketching, sketching w/ basic grid templates, sometimes cardboard stencils for often used elements, …) and then most often OmniGraffle at a later stage, sometimes supplemented by Indesign, Fireworks (only with certain clients, if hifi comps are required – otherwise its GUI performance is a major PITA) or Keynote (great if you need all kinds of transitions). I am currently considering migrating to Axure RP, though. Moving past paper prototypes and clickable mockups currently leaves basically the native format, i.e. most often HTML/JS (incl. jQuery). Balsamiq and other browser based solutions or RIAs so far have felt too slow und awkward for me, I just can't seem to get into flow with them. (Pidoco's collaboration and testing features might be interesting under certain circumstances, though.)

Answer (score 1):

I use Gliffy (online tool) for simple wireframes

Answer (score 1):

> [Mockingbird](http://gomockingbird.com/) is an online tool that makes it easy for you to create, link together, preview, and share mockups of your website or application.

It's still early beta and am not sure of the pricing, but it's worth keeping an eye on.  It's a web app written in Cappuccino so no need for Flash...

Cheers
R

Answer (score 1):

While I'm sure many of these tools are much better, here is a "low-tech" solution (given that you have PowerPoint) http://www.raizlabs.com/blog/294/wireframing-in-powerpoint

Answer (score 1):

Throwing in a resource in **to support sketching as a great wireframing tool:

[50 Sketching Resources for User Experience Designers](http://www.inspireux.com/2010/06/28/50-sketching-resources-for-user-experience-designers/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+Inspireux+%28inspireUX%29)** which includes sketching:

- articles
- tools
- templates
- presentations
- videos
- books
- examples

Answer (score 1):

Firefox Pencil Plugin is another tool to check out.

http://pencil.evolus.vn/en-US/Home.aspx

Its free, has a nice basic set of stencils, and some sketchy stencils.  You can get some rough mockups done pretty quickly.  Not as many stencils as other tools, but it works pretty well.

Comment: Seems to be broken in the latest Firefox, though. Also, doesn't look like it's been updated in over a year. Still, looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

I use Axure, and kind of satisfied with it.
I wuold have some development ideas, to make usability of the program more convenient and faster.
For example there are missing features when dealing with text (alignments, text-picture alignment, etc.)

I haven't tried other stuff yet!

Answer (score 1):

[WireframeSketcher](http://wireframesketcher.com) is a software tool that helps quickly create wireframes, mockups and prototypes for desktop, web and mobile applications. It comes both as a plug-in for any Eclipse-based IDEs and a standalone version.

[image: WireframeSketcher Website Mockup]

Answer (score 1):

I use Justinmind, great to wireframe and prototype dynamic websites (JS-like events & integrate your own data) without coding (even interactions are drag & dropped).

They also offer a service to share your wireframes online so that people can comment straight on elements & you can even carry out user tests as it integrates most user testing tools (clicktale, userzoom, google analytics...).

http://www.justinmind.com

Answer (score 1):

I've found MS Visio to be pretty flexible if you've got the right supporting files. I use...

**[Visio - the interaction designer's nail gun (3rd edition)](http://www.guuui.com/issues/02_07.php)**
Basic web widgets in standard and "sketchy" versions

**[Visio tips & tricks for Interaction Designers](http://www.welie.com/visio/index.php)**
Macros that make working with Visio much easier. In particular, copying pages and copy/paste items "in place".

Answer (score 0):

Here's an online tool that has a **Free plan** as well as really cheap one at $50/year:
http://www.mockflow.com/

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting pretty tired of the people saying they are only using pen and paper.

If you can make complex frameworks with pen and paper then either you are non-efficient or never reuse modules from earlier designs or this is your first one ;)

The whole point with a tool for sketching must be to make a pattern library and use it so you can focus on the bits of the project thats interesting and innovative instead of the boring parts you have done so many times before.

The whole "I only use pen and paper" reminds me of the days when every HTML coder with any pride claimed that he never used anything else than notepad to code. Ok, the tools back in the day was bad (remember Frontpage?) - but still...

Comon! Of course you use pen and paper sometimes, but seriously, when people ask for advice about tools - don't mock them suggesting pen and paper - don't you think they know about pen and paper before they asked the question?

I use Axure. It's not pretty but it gets the job done.

(Don't get me started on those who say they jump straight to HTML. They are worse than the pen and paper ppl.)

Comment: Sorry, not quite. The basic point about sketching is to generate ideas as quick and cheap as possible for later evaluation. You can't beat paper in that respect. And in case you really need certain library elements you may just print and cut them out and/or use simple cardboard stencils. When you have narrowed down possible options and need higher fidelity it's time to move on to suitable software, of course.

Comment: Must be my bad sketching skills. In 9 of 10 times I get started faster without it. The one time pen and paper is faster is when I get to deliver it more or less straight to the designer. But in those cases its usually just revisions of existing stuff we have made together earlier.

Comment: It's not an either or...it's using the right tool for the situation. Sometimes its Axure, sometimes it's pen and paper. I prefer pen, paper --> HTML/CSS/JS. Axure has its uses, but it slower to wireframe in than paper, and and limited in the fidelity an the high end given its code framework. As always, it depends on the project and the team.

Answer (score 0):

I use ForeUI that is a great tool for creating prototypes, in which you can add behaviour to simulate rather complex system behaviour. - If that's required for your prototype.

The DHTML prototype can be exported and run in any browser, that support java, and easily be shared with colleagues and customers.

I'm designing software for Windows, but ForeUI can be used for anything - including web.

It runs on Windows, Mac, Linux, and Solaris and the price i $99. Usually a new version is released every fortnight. Find more details on www.foreui.com.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add a FREE, FAST, BASIC, ONLINE MockUp builder: (Silverlight required)
http://www.mockupbuilder.com/App

I use it when I need something draft, fast, online!